# Elastic search query for two fields

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm trying to write a query for some products.  Products have two fields, title and description.  I'd like to write a query that passes in some text and returns to me products with matching text.  I'd like all the products that have a match in the title to be ranked above all the products that have a match in the description.  I'd also like to have the description field matches to require a higher fuzziness and minimum should match than title matches.

So far i've only been able to find ways to write queries that
A) would check both fields, but matches for title and description would ranked equivalently
or 
b) would check both fields, but would require a match in both fields before returning a result.

Any help writing this in either the regular elastic search or using the FOSElasticaBundle would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In elastic search you can make use of the [query string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to provide different boost to different fields. This supports boolean search texts also. In case you do not need boolean search text then you can use [multi-match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) also.